# Why won't my web browser reflect changes I made on the server?

Tags: html, web, shared-hosting, public-html

This is as simple as it gets. My school provides us with a personal storage that can be used for a webpage. Its the standard http://www.example.com/~studentname type deal. Previously, I would make changes to an index.html file and upload in using the 'Secure File Transfer Client' to my public_html folder. I'd hit refresh, and bingo.

I used ssh to login remotely edited the .html file with pico, and saved it. if I do a cat on the file after closing it, it's still there. But my neither firefox nor google chrome reflect the recent changes. I've even deleted my cache to no avail.

Comment: If you upload the file with a different file name does the new file show?

Comment: no, i copied the index.html to index2.html, then typed that into the browser, and got the school's 404 page. I'm just gonna assume its an issue with the school. I deleted the index.html and the page loaded as if I never touched it.

Comment: check my comment on my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my school moved to a new web environment, and was no longer using the public_html directory to serve student and faculty webpages.

Answer (score 2):

I've definitely run into cases where even after refreshing my browser cache and any other cache I had control over there was still an external proxy or server-side cache that couldn't be forcibly refreshed. In that case renaming the file should at least get you a current version. If that fixes it, that's the problem.

The only other time I've had this problem was in a situation where files were checked out from their editable location to their final served location via a post-commit hook, and that script broke. But that's pretty much definitely not the case for you. I'm just throwing it out there as another bizarre scenario that I know *I* wouldn't have thought of if it hadn't happened.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you are behind a proxy, which is still serving you the cached version?

how long ago did you edit your pages?

Comment: hmm.. there is another possible scenario: what you access using ssh/telnet is a middleman-server... it might have a cron job that uploads your pages to the main server everyday or so... this is how it is in my college....

Comment: its still hasn't changed a bit. (Its been 9 days)

Answer (score 0):

Is there http proxy between you and the host where your html files are served from ?

Sometimes also using "force refresh" helps, eg, not just pressing the refresh button. Check the section "Instructions for various browsers" in this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bypass_your_cache

Answer (score 0):

Try to view the page from another computer, just to make sure.

I don't know the infrastructure implemented in your school, but if they have a clustered environment, for instance, maybe you're changing the file in one server and what you're getting in your browser is published in another server.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with cache problems I add version number to file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css?5">`

Every update I just increase number after ?.
I won't help directly in your problem, but you can make your index.html always redirecting you to index2.html?random to be sure no cache is used.
Also you my want to check no-cache meta tags: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file to index.xxx or something in order to make sure it's the page that's being served.
If it's not a cache problem, it's maybe the wrong file that you're modifying
Edit: noticed your latest comments. It means the files are not served from your local folder, but from somewhere else ( and that place is not automatically updated when you save your files) or ... maybe there's a configuration problem ( server looking in a different folder)